# Joining three table levels by single key

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, join

**Scenario:** I have 3 tables (higher, mid, and lower levels). Each item in the Higher table can contain several rows of items in the mid table. Lower table can contains aggregated values, which are connected to each item of the higher table.

**The logic:** the objective is to aggregate every row from mid table into the higher table (full join), and to those rows, aggregate the items of the lower table. All three table share the keyA column.

```
+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+
| keyA | HigherName | HigherValue | HigherStatus |
+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+
| 123 | Item1      | 100         | Active       |
+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+
| 124 | Item2      | 105         | Inactive     |
+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+
| 125 | Item3      | 96          | Inactive     |
+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+
| 126 | Item4      | 104         | Inactive     |
+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+
| 127 | Item5      | 89          | Active       |
+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+
| 128 | Item6      | 97          | Inactive     |
+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+
```

**EX Mid Table:**

```
+-----+---------+----------+
| keyA | MidName | MidValue |
+-----+---------+----------+
| 123 | Mid1    | 55       |
+-----+---------+----------+
| 123 | Mid2    | 46       |
+-----+---------+----------+
| 123 | Mid3    | 49       |
+-----+---------+----------+
| 124 | Stat1   | 41       |
+-----+---------+----------+
| 124 | Stat2   | 59       |
+-----+---------+----------+
| 124 | Stat3   | 51       |
+-----+---------+----------+
| 125 | Gen1    | 56       |
+-----+---------+----------+
| 125 | Gen2    | 57       |
+-----+---------+----------+
| 126 | Test1   | 44       |
+-----+---------+----------+
| 127 | Lev1    | 42       |
+-----+---------+----------+
| 127 | Lev2    | 49       |
+-----+---------+----------+
| 127 | Lev3    | 50       |
+-----+---------+----------+
| 127 | Lev4    | 60       |
+-----+---------+----------+
| 128 | Spec1   | 61       |
+-----+---------+----------+
| 128 | Spec2   | 39       |
+-----+---------+----------+
```

**EX Lower Table:**

```
+-----+-----------+------------+
| keyA | LowerName | LowerValue |
+-----+-----------+------------+
| 123 | Sub1      | 12         |
+-----+-----------+------------+
| 123 | Sub1      | 14         |
+-----+-----------+------------+
| 123 | Sub1      | 13         |
+-----+-----------+------------+
| 124 | Sub2      | 13         |
+-----+-----------+------------+
| 124 | Sub2      | 10         |
+-----+-----------+------------+
| 124 | Sub2      | 11         |
+-----+-----------+------------+
| 125 | Sub3      | 19         |
+-----+-----------+------------+
| 125 | Sub3      | 14         |
+-----+-----------+------------+
| 126 | Sub4      | 15         |
+-----+-----------+------------+
| 127 | Sub5      | 14         |
+-----+-----------+------------+
| 127 | Sub5      | 13         |
+-----+-----------+------------+
| 127 | Sub5      | 11         |
+-----+-----------+------------+
| 127 | Sub5      | 10         |
+-----+-----------+------------+
| 128 | Sub6      | 11         |
+-----+-----------+------------+
| 128 | Sub6      | 12         |
+-----+-----------+------------+
```

**EX Output:**

```
+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
| keyA | HigherName | HigherValue | HigherStatus | MidName | MidValue | LowerName | LowerValue |
+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 123 | Item1      | 100         | Active       | Mid1    | 55       | Sub1      | 12         |
+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 123 | Item1      | 100         | Active       | Mid2    | 46       | Sub1      | 14         |
+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 123 | Item1      | 100         | Active       | Mid3    | 49       | Sub1      | 13         |
+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 124 | Item2      | 105         | Inactive     | Stat1   | 41       | Sub2      | 13         |
+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 124 | Item2      | 105         | Inactive     | Stat2   | 59       | Sub2      | 10         |
+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 124 | Item2      | 105         | Inactive     | Stat3   | 51       | Sub2      | 11         |
+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 125 | Item3      | 96          | Inactive     | Gen1    | 56       | Sub3      | 19         |
+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 125 | Item3      | 96          | Inactive     | Gen2    | 57       | Sub3      | 14         |
+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 126 | Item4      | 104         | Inactive     | Test1   | 44       | Sub4      | 15         |
+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 127 | Item5      | 89          | Active       | Lev1    | 42       | Sub5      | 14         |
+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 127 | Item5      | 89          | Active       | Lev2    | 49       | Sub5      | 13         |
+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 127 | Item5      | 89          | Active       | Lev3    | 50       | Sub5      | 11         |
+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 127 | Item5      | 89          | Active       | Lev4    | 60       | Sub5      | 10         |
+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 128 | Item6      | 97          | Inactive     | Spec1   | 61       | Sub6      | 11         |
+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
| 128 | Item6      | 97          | Inactive     | Spec2   | 39       | Sub6      | 12         |
+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
```

**What I did:** I was trying to use a full join to combine the tables. When using a full join between higher and mid, everything worked fine. But when I try to include Lower, I get the error:

```
'databaseA.higher.keyA' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

**Question:** What am I doing wrong, and how to fix this?

**Code so far:**

```
Select 
    [keyA ] = databaseA.higher.keyA,
    [Higher Name ] = databaseA.higher.higher_name,
    [Higher Value ] = databaseA.higher.higher_value,
    [Higher Status ] = databaseA.higher.higher_status,
    [Mid Name ] = databaseA.mid.mid_status,
    [Mid Value ] = databaseA.mid.mid_value,
    [Lower Name ] = databaseA.lowerA.LowerA_status,
    [Lower Value ] = databaseA.lowerA.lowerA_value
from databaseA.higher
FULL JOIN databaseA.mid
    on databaseA.higher.keyA = databaseA.mid.keyA
Full JOIN databaseA.lower
    on databaseA.higher.keyA = databaseA.lower.keyA
where databaseA.higher.keyA in ('82487')
```

Comment: Please explain the logic for the combining the tables, and add a database tag.

Comment: That query contains several errors. And can still not give the described error message.

Comment: `FULL JOIN databaseA.mid
    on databaseA.higher.keyA = databaseA.higher.keyA.keyA
INNER JOIN databaseA.mid
    on databaseA.higher.keyA = databaseA.mid.keyA`
You are joining the `mid` table 2 times. The `FULL JOIN` is using the `higher.keyA` only. And I think this is wrong `databaseA.higher.keyA.keyA`. Please help us understand further.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added to the question. The logic basically a full join of the three tables based on keyA.

Comment: @jarlh Fixed some mistakes in the OP.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I fixed that mistake in the OP.

Comment: Not that this would make a difference, but is `keyA` a `varchar` as opposed to an `int` datatype? Just wondering why you are referencing it as a string in the `Where` clause? And the expected output doesn't correspond with the query.

Comment: @WEI_DBA it is varchar. Just in the example for the OP i simplified.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
select
  h.*,
  x.midname, x.midvalue, x.lowername, x.lowervalue
from higher h
left join (
  select 
    coalesce(a.keya, b.keya) as keya,
    a.midname, a.midvalue, b.lowername, b.lowervalue
  from (
    select *,
      row_number() over(partition by keya order by midname) as rn
    from mid
  ) a
  full outer join (
    select *,
      row_number() over(partition by keya order by lowername) as rn
    from lower
  ) b on a.keya = b.keya and a.rn = b.rn
) x on h.keya = x.keya
```

You need to join the mid and lower tables using an artificial key (I added the `rn` column). Then just join the higher table against the previous result set.

Comment: Many thanks, I will test it now. Two questions: what is the effect of coalesce here? And why cannot I use the keyA to do the mapping?

Comment: `COALESCE()` is necessary since you are doing a full outer join. If you have mismatching number of rows in mid and lower (let's say 3 rows in mid and 5 in lower) then one of the keys could be null. If you always have the same number of rows in them, then this is not necessary.

Comment: To the second question. If you have 3 rows in mid and 3 rows in lower, then a join by keya will produce 9 rows. But you only want 3. That's why you need to join by an artificial key (keya, rn), where I created `rn` as a simple row number.

Comment: Many thanks, I understand. One last question: If the values of lower and higher could be connected directly (since what happens is that the same value of higher/lower will be repeated for each column of mid connected to it), would it be better to to the mapping between higher and lower and then map them to mid?

Comment: @DGMS89 Not entirely sure. It may depend on the nullability and cardinality of the mid and lower tables. Do you always have rows in mid and lower? Do you always have the same number of rows in mid and lower? The answer may depend on how the real data is layed out.

Comment: Not exactly, but the values from "lower" are aggregations that should be unique to each keya. So for a given keya, "higher" and "lower" values will just repeat for as many rows as "mid" has data for keya. Ex. Assume there is only 1 keya in "higher", If "mid" has 3 rows for that keya, the final table should have 3 rows, where the data of "mid" is different, but the data for "higher" and "lower" repeats in each of those rows (for the respective columns).